# How to preserve the scroll position of tabView when using collapsible app bar (sliverAppBar)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, nestedscrollview, scroll-position, flutter-sliver

#### Problem:

Scroll position of the tabView **is not** restored correctly when one of the tabView is scrolled to the top (revealing the sliverAppBar). The other tabView will also scrolled to the top (losing its previous scroll position).

- This problem **will not** show up if normal app bar is used (**not** collapsible app bar)
- This problem **only** shows up when the tabView is scrolled to top

#### Question:

How to preserve the scroll position of the tabView when using collapsible app bar (sliverAppBar)?

#### Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                title: Text('Example'),
                pinned: true,
                floating: true,
                forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                bottom: TabBar(
                  tabs: <Widget>[
                    Tab(text: 'One',),
                    Tab(text: 'Two'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                key: PageStorageKey<String>('one'),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new Text('One Item $index'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                key: PageStorageKey<String>('two'),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new Text('Two Item $index'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a [known issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40740) and still open. Although there is a workaround as [mentioned in this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40740#issuecomment-681764547):

> Here's a workaround that uses
> [`extended_nested_scroll_view`](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_nested_scroll_view/example)
> package. With this, I haven't encountered any issues (at least for
> now). So until flutter fixes this issue, this workaround seems
> sufficient. Only tested on Android.
>
> The basic gist of it is:
>
> - Use `NestedScrollView` from the package `extended_nested_scroll_view`
> - Wrap each tab view in a `StatefulWidget` with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and `wantKeepAlive => true`
> - Inside that `StatefulWidget`(s), wrap the scrollable content in `NestedScrollViewInnerScrollPositionKeyWidget`
> - Key values used in `innerScrollPositionKeyBuilder` and `NestedScrollViewInnerScrollPositionKeyWidget` must match.